# Using different settings for different projects

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a possibility to configure IntelliJ (12, ultimate) to use a specific type of setting only for a single project? I am bound to some style configuration that I do not want to use elsewhere and I hate reimporting settings when I switch between projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some settings are IDE wide, others are Project Specific. When you go into *File > Settings*, you will see the settings divided into two sections (Project and IDE).

Code Style (i.e. formatting) is a project specific setting. Go to *File > Settings [Project Settings] > Code Style*. There you can change the code style scheme used by a project. To create a new style scheme, click the manage button and then copy one to use as the base. Whatever style scheme you select will apply to the current project. But you can share a scheme across projects if desired. Thus you could have ab "Apache" scheme that conforms to requirements for when you work on Apache open source projects, a "Department X" and  "Department Y" schemes for when working on projects for those departments. If you tweak a setting in the "Department X" setting, it will affect all projects that use that scheme. You can set the default scheme to use when creating new projects in *File > Other Settings > Default Settings*.

Also on the in the dialog that opens when you click the "manage" button is an option to "copy to project". Clicking this button will copy the selected code style into the Project Settings (i.e. the .idea directory). If you want to share a code style with other developers via source control, this is something you will want to do. This makes the settings very project specific. Any tweaks to it only affect the current project. And you can not easily copy it to a new project.